# Display real time terminal output on button click event in reactjs

Tags: python, reactjs, api, flask, live-streaming

I have used a number of methods to solve this problem but end up getting a new issue to resolve, now I give up please help me(also I'm new to react and flask).

this is my reactjs code:

```
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet-async';
import { faker } from '@faker-js/faker';
import  { useState, useEffect } from "react";

// @mui
import { useTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { Grid, Container, Typography , Button} from '@mui/material';


const info = async()=>{
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/data");
  const body = await res.json();
  return body.message;
}




export default function DashboardAppPage() {
  const theme = useTheme();
//  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

 // const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
 // const handleShow = () => setShow(true);
  const [data, setdata] = useState( []);

// useEffect(()=>{
//   const item = ()=>{
//     fetch("/data").then((res) =>
//               res.json().then((data) => {
//                   // Setting a data from api
//                   setdata(data.message);
//                   console.log("Succes", data.message)
//               })
//           );
//   }
//   const interval = setInterval(item,2000);
//   return () => clearInterval(interval);

// },[])
 

const onClickHandler=async()=>{
  
  const text = await info();
  // const interval = setInterval(text, 1000);
  // clearInterval(interval);
  setdata(...text)
  console.log("Clicked")
}
 
 

  return (
    <>
      <Helmet>
        <title> Dashboard | Minimal UI </title>
      </Helmet>

      <Container maxWidth="xl">
      <Button variant="contained" onClick={onClickHandler} sx={{ mb: 5 }}> 
              Scan System
      </Button> 
      <Typography variant="h4" sx={{ mb: 5 }}>
      <iframe title="MyFrame" 
                style={{ backgroundColor: "transparent", width: "100%", height: "100%"}} 
                src="http://localhost:5000/data" />

      </Typography>

      <Typography variant="h4" sx={{ mb: 5 }}> {data}</Typography>
</>
 );
}
```

and this is my flask code:

```
  from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request,render_template,jsonify ,Response
from flask_cors import CORS
import os
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route('/data', methods=['GET','POST'])
def home():
    # try:
        data=None
        data = Popen('sudo chkrootkit', 
        bufsize=1,
        stdout = PIPE, 
        stderr = STDOUT, 
        shell = True)
        # data = subprocess.check_output(

        #     "sudo chkrootkit",
        # stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
        # shell=True,
        # text=True)
        # subprocess.check_output("dir /f",shell=True,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        while True:
            out = data.stdout.readline().decode()
            # line = data.stdout.next().replace('\n', '')
            print(out)
            yield out + '<br/>\n'
            if not out:
                break
        # return data.stdout.readline()
            
        return {
            "message":Response(home(), mimetype='text/html')
        }
    # except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    #     raise RuntimeError("command '{}' return with error (code {}): {}".format(e.cmd, e.returncode, e.output))   

# @app.route('/')
# def index():
#     """
#     Render a template at the index. The content will be embedded in this template
#     """
#     return render_template('index.html')

if(__name__=='__main__'):  #This is so that we can run it directly in debug mode
    app.run(debug=True)
```

i am currently using iframe to display the data which i believe is not the right way to do it plus onclick handler is doing nothing.
I cannot use *useState* and *useEffect* inside event hanlder as it is against the rules.
I also thought of using webSockets but I don't think it's possible to render data through a click.
so finally,
please help me get the live data on a button click in the reactjs code.